# How to have Cucumber let Spring inject step definition classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, kotlin

I have a SpringBootApplication which executes Cucumber (not as part of the tests but as the main application).

I happen to do this in Kotlin, but that should not matter.

This is the application class. The body of `demo02` is copied from some Cucumber sources and has been working fine. I think there is nothing wrong with it.

```
package cutest

import ...

@CucumberOptions(tags = arrayOf("not @ignore"),
            features = arrayOf("sandbox/cutest/src/main/resources"),
            // features = arrayOf("src/main/resources"),
            format = arrayOf(
                    "pretty",
                    "html:target/site/cucumber/cucumber",
                    "json:target/failsafe-reports/cucumber.json"
            ),
            strict = true)
@SpringBootApplication
open class CucumberApplication {

    @Bean
    open fun demo02() = CommandLineRunner {

        val cl : ClassLoader = javaClass.getClassLoader()
        val rl = MultiLoader(cl)
        val roFactory = RuntimeOptionsFactory(this.javaClass)

        val ro = roFactory.create()

        val classFinder : ClassFinder = ResourceLoaderClassFinder(rl, cl)
        val runtime : cucumber.runtime.Runtime = cucumber.runtime.Runtime(rl, classFinder, cl, ro)
        runtime.run()

        if(runtime.exitStatus().toInt() != 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("exit status: " + runtime.exitStatus());
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(CucumberApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Then I have a feature file:

```
Feature: Server is reachable
  Here I try to connect to my web server app

  @Basic
  Scenario: Can connect to REST service of the web server
    Given Cucumber is up and running
    Then I can connect to the REST web server
```

Here are simple working Step Definitions, matching and passing the step `Given Cucumber is up and running`:

```
package cutest

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given

class SomeSteps {    
    class SomeStepDefs {    
        @Given(value = """^Cucumber is up and running$""")
        fun a() {
            assert(true)
        }    
    }
}
```

And now the problematic Step Definitions. It has some `@Autowired` annotations in it which seem to be problematic:

```
package cutest

import ...

class RestSteps {

    @Autowired lateinit var ssh : PortForwardSshR

    @Value("\${cutest.url}")
    private val url = "http://example.com:8080/app/rest"

    @Given(value = """^I can connect to the REST web server$""")
    fun connectRest() {
        ....    
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Feature: Cucumber is present
  Cucumber framework must be up and running

  @Basic
  Scenario: Cucumber works          
    Given Cucumber is up and running

Feature: Reseller Interface is reachable
  Here I try to ...

  @Basic
  Scenario: Can connect to REST service of the web server
    Given Cucumber is up and running
    Then I can connect to the REST web server


  kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property ssh has not been initialized
at cutest.RestSteps.connectRest(RestSteps.kt:47)
at ✽.I can connect to the CAPs 
...

Failed scenarios:

... cutest/rest.feature:7

2 Scenarios (1 failed, 1 passed)
3 Steps (1 failed, 2 passed)
```

There probably not much more information in the stacktrace, but here it is:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property ssh has not been initialized
at cutest.RestSteps.connectRest(RestSteps.kt:47)
at ✽.I can connect to the CAPs ResellerInterface(...cutest/rest.feature:9)

2017-11-07 13:46:08.974  INFO 11433 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-07 13:46:08.985 ERROR 11433 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at cutest.CucumberApplicationKt.main(CucumberApplication.kt:50) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: exit status: 1
at vc.capper.cutest.CucumberApplication$demo02$1.run(CucumberApplication.kt:44) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
... 11 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you include `cucumber-spring`  as dependency?

Comment: I wrote a blogpost about Cucumber and dependency injection using Spring. Maybe it can give you a hint, http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/06/24/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-spring

Comment: Do you have a Bean `PortForwardSshR`?

Comment: @Marit I think I had, but I can check again